# System references in bamboo

Tags: c#, .net, bamboo, system.reflection

I have installed one nuget package in my project which has dependency on some of the system dlls like `system.IO/system.Reflection` etc. So when I install that nuget package everything works fine in my local. However, when I push my code to bamboo (build server) I start getting multiple assemblies error:

```
26-Mar-2019 05:30:23      CSC : error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'E:\agt01\ENS-EB577-BEQI\Bin\Packages\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references. [E:\agt01\ENS-EB577-BEQI\myProject\myProject.csproj]
26-Mar-2019 05:30:23      CSC : error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'E:\agt01\ENS-EB577-BEQI\Bin\Packages\System.Runtime.InteropServices.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references. [E:\agt01\ENS-EB577-BEQI\myProject\myProject.csproj]
26-Mar-2019 05:30:23      CSC : error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'E:\agt01\ENS-EB577-BEQI\Bin\Packages\System.Reflection.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Reflection.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Reflection.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references. [E:\agt01\ENS-EB577-BEQI\myProject\myProject.csproj]
26-Mar-2019 05:30:23      CSC : error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'E:\agt01\ENS-EB577-BEQI\Bin\Packages\System.IO.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.IO.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.IO.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references. [E:\agt01\myProject-EB577-BEQI\myProject\myProject.csproj]
26-Mar-2019 05:30:23    
26-Mar-2019 05:30:23        617 Warning(s)
26-Mar-2019 05:30:23        4 Error(s)
```

So basically bamboo is trying to pick those system dlls from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\`

So to work that around, I have to make sure I remove these references from my csproj as nuget packages and push to bamboo in order to get a successful build but when testing in my local I have to add them as nuget packages to get things to work.

Has any one faced such issue before?

Answer (score 0):

For the specific errors you included, it looks as though you have duplicate imports of the assemblies within your `.csproj` file. I would open up the `myProject.csproj` and pick either the ones in `Bin\Packages` or the System ones installed as part of the .Net Framework install.

I personally would go with the System installed ones that were put there as part of the framework install. If you are having issues finding those on the Bamboo agent, make sure that .NET Framework 4.6.2 is installed on the build agent in the specified location (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2`)